# Unity 5.3 Google play service and AdMob crushing my APP

Tags: c#, android, admob, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with `AdMob`. When I call interstitial or banner the application crushes.

Errors:

```
Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd', referenced from method com.google.unity.ads.Interstitial$1.run
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd
```

When I apply the folder `google-play-service-lib` from the Android SDK, Unity automatically deletes it. If someone has the same problem or a similar, please help.

Comment: `google-play-service-lib` folder is where the Google play service at. If it gone, you cannot use Google play service like `admob`. You can first try to find the reason why the folder has gone. or use this repo https://github.com/nabrozidhs/unity_admob_android instead

Comment: Try to update the play services SDK to the latest version using the SDK Manager. Within Unity, this is `Window > Google Play Games > Downloads > Google Play Games SDK (Android)`...
Then run the Play Games Setup again, `Window > Google Play Games > Setup > Android Setup`... This will copy the update client library into your Unity project.

Comment: @Yarasa Lisill have you found a solution to this problem?